# Dcm4chee Connection to ldap://ldap:389 broken - reconnect error

Tags: ldap, dcm4che

I'm using dcm4chee docker stack with ldap and postgreSQL and have a floating error:

```
ldap:389; socket closed; remaining name 'cn=Devices,cn=DICOM Configuration,dc=mdw,dc=io'
2018-07-13 06:30:42,089 INFO  [org.dcm4che3.conf.ldap.ReconnectDirContext] (Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)) Connection to ldap://ldap:389 broken - reconnect
```

All three services are running on the same host. What can I do to avoid that error?

Answer (score 0):

Disable the firewall. If firewall was enabled add an exception for all 3 services.

Comment: Thank you for reply. This is not a permanent error. It raises sometime and I can't figure out why. Most of the time dcm4chee is working normally. But sometimes this error happens.  Firewall is enabled, but all services can communicate with each other.

Comment: Then it could be port number also. Change your port accordingly and that port number should be dedicate for the dcm4chee

Comment: This is not related to port configuration. Most of time all works just as it should, but sometimes there is such error.